# if there is a number after a substring, repeat that substring by that amount of number (javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements, nested-loops

entirely new to coding and learning javascript. I am given an assignment to make a simple program where in if the string is for example "I do2 lo1ve ste3ak"

the output would be "i dooo loove steeeeak"

basically, given a string, if there is a number after a letter,replace that number with the string before, by the amount of the number. the number present will always be between 1 and 9.

**The restriction is that i am not allowed to use any other built in functions other than one that convert number to string and vicer versa e.g toString(), Number().**

the example below, the output is supposed to be "I Loove Cooooodinggg", However i am not getting it no matter what i try

```js
let word = 'I Lo1ve Co4ding2'

let temp = '' // temporary storage

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) { // check each value of word
  if ((Number(word[i]) > 0)) { // converts value to number and check if bigger than 0 
    for (let j = 0; j < word[i]; j++) { // if bigger than one, then repeat word before it 
      temp += word[i - 1]
    }
  } else { // put character in output
    temp += word[i]
  }
  console.log(temp)
}

if (word == "") {
  console.log('no words can be processed')
}
```

Comment: I added a snippet. The code's output matches "I Loove Cooooodinggg". I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: its suppose to just show only the last line, not the previous ones.

Comment: Just move the `console.log` outside of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I came up with. It converts the string to type "number" using built-in `parseInt` method then checks if its **NaN** using `isNaN`

```js
const repeatNum = (str) => {
    let result = "";
  for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    let temp = parseInt(str[i]);
    if(!isNaN(temp)){
      for(let j=0; j<temp; j++){
        result += str[i-1];
      }
    }else{
        result+= str[i]
    }
    
  }
 return result; 
}

let inputStr1 = "I do2 lo1ve ste3ak";
let inputStr2 = "I Lo1ve Co4ding2";

console.log(repeatNum(inputStr1));
console.log(repeatNum(inputStr2));
```